# How do I IF with 3 conditions in VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement, bids

I have a field in a report with 4 potential values, "A", "B", "C" & "D".
The following code makes the font color "red" for "C" and "D" and "black" for all other values. How do I add another statement to make the color "green" for value "A"?

```
<Color>=IIF((Fields!DFEE_condition.Value = "C") or (Fields!DFEE_condition.Value = "D"),"Red","Black")</Color>
```

Thanks

Comment: This is tagged both VBA and VB.NET, it can't be both so which is it? I suspect VB.NET but I don't want to jump to an incorrect conclusion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to reuse IIF statement like this :

```
<Color>=IIF((Fields!DFEE_condition.Value = "C") or (Fields!DFEE_condition.Value = "D"),"Red",IIF((Fields!DFEE_condition.Value = "A"),"Green","Black"))</Color>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert `[A..D]` to `[1..4]` and `Choose()`:

```
color = choose(asc(Fields!DFEE_condition.Value)-64, "Green", "Black", "Red", "Red")
```

(If you can use statements, you would `Select Case`)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<Color>
=IIF((Fields!DFEE_condition.Value = "A"), "Green", IIF(Fields!DFEE_condition.Value = "C") or (Fields!DFEE_condition.Value = "D"), "Red", "Black"))
</Color>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write nested iif's ;)

```
result = IIF(condition1, value_if_true, IIF(condition2, value_if_true, value_if_false))
```